# Error when trying to add MVC 4 controller: 'EntityClass' is not part of of the specified 'ContextClass' class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

So I'm working on a practice project using Visual Studio 2012, MVC 4, and Entity Framework 5.0. I create an MVC 4 project using the "Basic" template. I add a simple Home/Index controller and view just to make sure everything is working. It is.

I add an edmx data model to my project under the models folder. (Connection strings are tested and good). I generate this model from a fairly simple SQL Express database. Here's some details about the model (generic names substituted):

Model edmx file structure looks like this in Solution Explorer:

```
[edmxFile] MyProjectModel.edmx
    [SubFile] MyProjectModel.Context.cs
         [Class] MyProjectEntities
             [Method] MyProjectEntities()
             [Method] OnModelCreating()
             [Property] EntityAs: DbSet<EntityA>
             [Property] EntityBs: DbSet<EntityB>
             [Property] EntityCs: DbSet<EntityC>
             etc...
    [SubFile] MyProjectModel.Designer.cs
    [SubFile] MyProjectModel.edmx.diagram
    [SubFile] MyProjectModel.tt
         [ClassFile] EntityA.cs
         [ClassFile] EntityB.cs
         [ClassFile] EntityC.cs
         etc...
         [ClassFile] MyProjectModel.cs
```

So I Rebuild my solution, then right click the "Controllers" folder and choose "Add"->"Controller" and choose the following options:

- Controller name: "EntityAsController".
- Scaffolding options:

  - Template: MVC controller with read/write actions and views, using Entity Framework
  - Model class: EntityA (MyProject.Models)
  - Data context class: MyProjectEntities (MyProject.Models)
  - Views: Razor (CSHTML)

Then I click "Add". I get the following error (again, generic names substituted):

**'MyProject.Models.EntityA' is not part of the specified 'MyProject.Models.MyProjectEntities' class, and the 'MyProject.Models.MyProjectEntities' class could not be modified to add a 'DbSet<MyProject.Models.EntityA>' property to it. (For example, the 'MyProject.Models.MyProjectEntities' class might be in a compiled assembly.)**

I originally got this error when I tried putting the edmx in a data layer project of its own and referencing that project from the main project. To solve,

- I tried moving it to the main project. No luck.
- I tried recreating the entire solution from scratch and creating it in the main project from the start. Same error.
- I read and tried monkeying around with just about every solution or suggestion in this question/answer(s)/comment(s): [Entity Framework MVC Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437656/entity-framework-mvc-controller) no success.
- I tried extending MyProjectEntities with a partial class and adding a wrapper property in order to FORCE it to have the desired "EntityA" property, like so:

`public DbSet<EntityA> EntityA {
        get { return this.EntityAs; }
        set { this.EntityAs = value; }
    }`

All that did was give me an even more unhelpful error:

**There was an error generating 'MyProject.Models.MyProjectEntities'. Try rebuilding your project.**

- I tried rebuilding the project. Same error.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my own problem. It's a bit hacky, but it works.

The first error message above complains about "...**class could not be modified to add a 'DbSet<MyProject.Models.EntityA>' property to it**...". So I left my partial class for extending `MyProject.Models.MyProjectEntities` empty, like so:

```
public partial class MyProjectEntities : DbContext
{
}
```

Now, when I create the controller, MVC is of course still to stupid to see that the auto generated `MyProjectEntities` already contains the property it wants, *BUT* it now has a file for that class that it can modify to add a duplicate declaration of that property, modifying my code to look like this:

```
public partial class MyProjectEntities : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<EntityA> EntityAs { get; set; }
}
```

It is happy, and makes my controller and views for me. Now, I just manually delete what it added to my code, so that there isn't an ambiguity error at build time. I build the project, start it, fire up my browser and go to "[siteUrl]/EntityAs", and TADA! It Works!

I hope that helps someone who has this problem. If anyone knows why MVC 4 and VS 2012 behave in this buggy way and require this hack solution, please comment or add another answer. It still bugs me a bit, and I'd love to hear more about it.